# Material Switch not working as expected in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application with material switch. I have given the conditions so that if it is on, display the table or else display treemap. But looks like there is some error in my code. Can anyone help me?
I think i have given the right conditions but not sure why  it is not working

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("sd"),
  dataTableOutput("iris"),
  
  # switchInput(inputId = "tp", value = TRUE, onLabel = "Table View", offLabel = "Tree Map",width = 1500, size = 'large')
  # radioButtons(inputId = "tp",choices = c("on","off"),selected = "on")
  materialSwitch(inputId = "tp", label = "Table View", status = "danger")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dtd7 <- structure(
    list(
      topic = structure(
        c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
          5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
        .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", "Carrot", "Mango","Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      n = structure(
        c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L,
          7L, 8L, 1L),
        .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      link = structure(c("<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>"))
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-13L)
  )


  observe({
    if(input$tp == TRUE){
  output$sd <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      dtd7,
      labels = ~ topic,
      parents = NA,
      values = ~ n,
      type = 'treemap', source = event_data("plotly_click"),
      hovertemplate = "Ingredient: %{label}<br>Count: %{value}<extra></extra>"
    )
  })
    }
    else {
      output$iris <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(iris)
      })
    }
})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to achieve this.....................?

Answer (score 0):

Perhps, this might help -

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("sd"),
  dataTableOutput("iris"),
  materialSwitch(inputId = "tp", label = "Table View", status = "danger")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dtd7 <- structure(
    list(
      topic = structure(
        c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
          5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
        .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", "Carrot", "Mango","Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      n = structure(
        c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L,
          7L, 8L, 1L),
        .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      link = structure(c("<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>","<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>",
                         "<a href = 'https://www.google.co.in/'>google</a>"))
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-13L)
  )
  
  
  output$sd <- renderPlotly({
        if(input$tp) {
        plot_ly(
          dtd7,
          labels = ~ topic,
          parents = NA,
          values = ~ n,
          type = 'treemap', source = event_data("plotly_click"),
          hovertemplate = "Ingredient: %{label}<br>Count: %{value}<extra></extra>"
        )
        }
      })
  
    output$iris <- renderDataTable({
      if(!input$tp) {
        datatable(iris)
      }
      })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```